How to avoid duplication in UIcollectionview

I have a trouble with my uikit app,
I have a tabbar with 3 navigation: List, Search, Account.

In my account page, i have an uicollectionview to display favourite list.
I want every time i go to this page using tabbar, uicollectionview will reload data, and update view, but i don't know how to delete my old view and replace it with new view.
My code:
-Tabbar:
class TabbarViewController: UITabBarController {
    var currentUser: User
    
    init(currentUser: User) {
        self.currentUser = currentUser
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    
    //MARK: -LyfeCycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let vc1 = ListMovieViewController()
        let vc2 = SearchViewController()
        let vc3 = AccountInfoViewController()
        
        let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)
        let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)
        let nav3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc3)
        
        nav1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "List", image: UIImage(systemName: "house"), tag: 1)
        nav2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Search", image: UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass"), tag: 1)
        nav3.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Account", image: UIImage(systemName: "person"), tag: 1)
        
        tabBar.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        
        setViewControllers([nav1, nav2, nav3], animated: false)
        
        print(currentUser.uid)
        
        self.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        //VerifyEm
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            if !currentUser.isEmailVerified {
                currentUser.sendEmailVerification { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error sending email verification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Email Verification", message: """
                                                                                            A verification link has been sent to your email address.
                                                                                                    Please verify your email and refresh the app.
                                                                                            """, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        print("Email verification sent successfully.")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Email Verification", message: """
                                                                                            A verification link has been sent to your email address.
                                                                                                    Please verify your email and refresh the app.
                                                                                            """, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            else if currentUser.isEmailVerified{
                let loadingAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Loading...", preferredStyle: .alert)
                self.present(loadingAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                    loadingAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    }
}

extension TabbarViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController,
           let accountInfoVC = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? AccountInfoViewController {
            accountInfoVC.reloadController()
        }
    }
}


FavouriteListViewController:

import UIKit

class FavouriteListViewController: UIViewController {

    private var vm = FavouriteViewModel()
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        title = "Favourite list"
        setUpCollectionView()
        fetchFavouriteData()
    }
    func reloadData(){
        fetchFavouriteData()
    }

    private func setUpCollectionView() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.register(FilmFavCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "FilmFavCell")

        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
        ])
    }

    private func fetchFavouriteData() {
        vm.getListFavourite { list in
            print(list ?? "")
        }
        vm.fetchFavDataFromFirebase {
            print("fetch data!")
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

extension FavouriteListViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return vm.getLength()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FilmFavCell", for: indexPath) as! FilmFavCell
        let film = vm.filmFavArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView.downloaded(from: film.imageUrl)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let height = collectionView.frame.height - 20 // Trừ đi sectionInset.top và sectionInset.bottom
        let width = height * 0.66 // Tỉ lệ width:height là 2:3
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedFilm = vm.filmFavArray[indexPath.item]
        let detailVC = DetailViewController(film: selectedFilm)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
    }
}


AccountPage:

import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class AccountInfoViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let viewModel = AccountInfoViewModel()
    
    // MARK: - UI Components
    private let titleLbl: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "Account information"
        label.textColor = .systemGray
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        return label
    }()
    
    private var avatar: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private var usernameLbl: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
        return label
    }()
    
    private var divider: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray4
        return view
    }()
    
    private var emailLbl: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "envelope.fill")
        imageView.tintColor = .systemGray
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private var emailContent: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .light)
        return label
    }()
    
    private var genderLbl: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle")
        imageView.tintColor = .systemGray
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private var genderContent: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .light)
        return label
    }()
    
    private var birthLbl: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "birthday.cake.fill")
        imageView.tintColor = .systemGray
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private var birthContent: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .light)
        return label
    }()
    
    private var dateJoinLbl: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "calendar.circle")
        imageView.tintColor = .systemGray
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private var dateJoinContent: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .light)
        return label
    }()
    
    private var editAvatarBtn: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "pencil.line")?.withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        button.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return button
    }()
    
    private var divider2: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray4
        return view
    }()
    
    private var favbtn: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        return button
    }()
    
    private var favView: UIView = {
        let favView = UIView()
        favView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return favView
    }()
    
    private lazy var childViewController: FavouriteListViewController = {
         let viewController = FavouriteListViewController()
         return viewController
    }()


    // MARK: - Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        title = "Account"
        self.reloadInputViews()
        setupViews()
        fetchUserInfo()
        
        let loadingAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Loading...", preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(loadingAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.2) {
            loadingAlert.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
        
    }

    // MARK: - Setup Views
    private func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(avatar)
        view.addSubview(usernameLbl)
        view.addSubview(divider)
        view.addSubview(titleLbl)
        view.addSubview(emailLbl)
        view.addSubview(emailContent)
        view.addSubview(genderLbl)
        view.addSubview(genderContent)
        view.addSubview(birthLbl)
        view.addSubview(birthContent)
        view.addSubview(dateJoinLbl)
        view.addSubview(dateJoinContent)
        view.addSubview(editAvatarBtn)
        view.addSubview(divider2)
        view.addSubview(favView)

        addChild(childViewController)
        favView.addSubview(childViewController.view)
        childViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            childViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favView.topAnchor),
            childViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favView.bottomAnchor),
            childViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favView.leadingAnchor),
            childViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favView.trailingAnchor)
        ])
        
        childViewController.didMove(toParent: self)

        
        avatar.image = UIImage(named: "avatar")
        avatar.layer.cornerRadius = avatar.frame.height / 2
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "line.3.horizontal"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuButtonTapped))
        
        editAvatarBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTappedAvatarEditBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            avatar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            avatar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            avatar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
            avatar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
            
            usernameLbl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            usernameLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: avatar.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            
            divider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            divider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            divider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            divider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1),
            
            titleLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 17),
            titleLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: divider.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            titleLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            
            emailLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 26),
            emailLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            emailLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            emailLbl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            
            emailContent.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailLbl.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            emailContent.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailLbl.centerYAnchor),
            emailContent.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            
            genderLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 26),
            genderLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 17),
            genderLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            genderLbl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            
            genderContent.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: genderLbl.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            genderContent.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: genderLbl.centerYAnchor),
            genderContent.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            
            birthLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 26),
            birthLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: genderLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 17),
            birthLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            birthLbl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            
            birthContent.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: birthLbl.trailingAnchor, constant: 11),
            birthContent.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: birthLbl.centerYAnchor, constant: 3),
            birthContent.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            
            dateJoinLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 26),
            dateJoinLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: birthLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            dateJoinLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            dateJoinLbl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            
            dateJoinContent.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateJoinLbl.trailingAnchor, constant: 11),
            dateJoinContent.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateJoinLbl.centerYAnchor),
            dateJoinContent.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            
            editAvatarBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38),
            editAvatarBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 38),
            editAvatarBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 40),
            editAvatarBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: usernameLbl.centerYAnchor, constant: -40),
            
            divider2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            divider2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            divider2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateJoinLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            divider2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1),
            
            favView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            favView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            favView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: divider2.bottomAnchor),
            favView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
            
        ])
        
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        avatar.layer.cornerRadius = avatar.frame.height / 2
        editAvatarBtn.layer.cornerRadius = editAvatarBtn.frame.height / 2
    }
    
    @objc func menuButtonTapped() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        let logoutAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Log out", style: .destructive) { _ in
            do {
                try Auth.auth().signOut()
                let loginVC = LoginViewController()
                let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)
                navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                
                let logoutSuccessAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Log out successfully", preferredStyle: .alert)
                self.present(logoutSuccessAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
                if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
                    if let window = windowScene.windows.first {
                        window.rootViewController = navController
                    }
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    logoutSuccessAlert.dismiss(animated: true)
                }
                
            } catch let signOutError as NSError {
                print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
            }
        }
        alert.addAction(logoutAction)
        
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func updateUI(with accountInfo: AccountInfo) {
        usernameLbl.text = accountInfo.username
        emailContent.text = accountInfo.email
        genderContent.text = accountInfo.gender
        birthContent.text = accountInfo.birthday
        dateJoinContent.text = accountInfo.dateJoined
        print(accountInfo.avatarURL)
    }

    func fetchUserInfo() {
        viewModel.fetchUserInfo { [weak self] accountInfo in
            guard let accountInfo = accountInfo else {
                // Handle error or no user info available
                return
            }
            
            // Update UI with user info
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.updateUI(with: accountInfo)
                self?.loadAvatar(from: accountInfo.avatarURL)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loadAvatar(from urlString: String) {
        viewModel.loadImage(from: urlString) { [weak self] image in
            guard let image = image else {
                return
            }
            self?.avatar.image = image
        }
    }
    
    @objc func didTappedAvatarEditBtn() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.editAvatarBtn.backgroundColor = self.editAvatarBtn.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        } completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.editAvatarBtn.backgroundColor = self.editAvatarBtn.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(1)
            }
        }
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func reloadController() {
        fetchUserInfo()
        childViewController.reloadData()
    }
    
}



extension AccountInfoViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            viewModel.uploadImageToFirebase(selectedImage) { imageURL in
                guard let imageURL = imageURL else {
                    return
                }
                print("Image uploaded successfully. URL:", imageURL)
                
                let newAvatar = "gs://film-valley.appspot.com/\(imageURL)"
                self.viewModel.updateAvatar(url: newAvatar)
            }
        }
        
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let updatedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Update Successfully!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(updatedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            updatedAlert.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}

Please tell me the way to solve my problem
My favourite list duplicated 1 film i liked:
AccountPage
When i add 1 more film:
AccountPage
i hope u guys can show me how to:

Delete old view and replace with new view
or
Reload accountpage when i click on account in tabbar

